# Cannot Resize Form by Dragging In Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a Winform I want to resize. Not **after** launching; I want to resize it in the *designer* by dragging the edges.

I am aware that I can change the size manually in the form properties. This is **not** what I want to do. I want to quickly size the default size of the form with my mouse.

The problem appears to be that I cannot grab the edges of the form for some reason. I repeat, this is **NOT DURING RUNTIME**. It is not that I have disabled/enabled Autosize/Resizing.

It's almost like the edge grabs are a single pixel wide and I just can't hit it. I don't know. I've looked for accessibility settings. The last thing I want to do is reinstall MSVS. It's just maddening.

I've attached a photo. The little boxes on the bottom, right, and bottom-right corner are my targets.

[image: Crappy form is crappy for now]

Comment: The little boxes are known as handles. Have you tried dragging them?

Comment: You can use c# to implement Winform to set the minimum size of the window when the mouse drags the window size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to click the form title before resizing. **I think** you may have a panel (or any container control) which is full docked in the form, that's why when you click the form body, you selected the panel instead of the form.

Another issue that I encountered was the windows font size was set to 120% (or more), so go to windows display setting and set the font size to 100%.

Comment: I actually figured it out and came back here to close it out and this was the problem! I restarted MSVS and got a pop up "Warning: Automatic Scaling has set your scaling to 125%. WPF/UWP XAML designers might not display correctly." 

I turned off Automatic scaling and set it back to 100%. Poof. All my issues are gone.